# GPU option is missing in Blender 2.69

Tags: gpu, blender

I am new learner of blender3D. I installed Ubuntu two days ago, and was struggling installing my nvidia and blender.Finally I managed but now I have a problem.

My **Preferences > System** does not show GPU option, (Once it worked yesterday but I ruined my installation trying to fix left mouse button issue).

What I want to achieve is run blender and get the utmost performance of my hardware on Linux Ubuntu

Details of PC : i7 processor, with Nvidia 640 graphic card.

Things I have done are:

Fresh install of Ubuntu and then installation of Nvidia driver

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Then I installed blender

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:irie/blender
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blender
```

So, now my blender is working, but in the system preference it shows **NO CPU** and when I go to render view, I don't see the environment texture. Only green and gray colored background. I am in doubt as to whether my Nvidia is properly installed, or cuda installation must be done.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. Now my GPU Rendering is working with one exception. The problem was the Blender package in ppa. I installed directly from the Blender website and now it works, exception is that it's not fast enough. CPU is faster.